# Multiple "if" conditions

Tags: php, if-statement

I got this code that gets a caption for how many comments there are in each post of my blog

```
$pego_comment_caption = " Comments";

if (get_comments_number($post->ID) == 1) {
    $pego_comment_caption = " Comment";
}
```

Since I'm more of a grammar nazi than I understand PHP, "0 Comments" is actually gramatically incorrect since 0 is less than 1 and.. well, you know

I'd like to change the `if` conditions making it display the word "Comment" instead of "Comments" when there are 0 OR 1 comment. It's probably simple but I couldn't do it. Does anybody know how to?

Comment: A true grammar Nazi would know that `0 Comments` is actually correct

Comment: But you don't need any OR at all: `if (get_comments_number($post->ID) <= 1) {`

Comment: Zero is something other than one of something, so it takes the plural. (Fractions of something also take the singular where they are expressed as 'half a thing' or 'two thirds of a thing', so the singular there is logical because you've referred to 'a thing'. You'd say '0.5 things', though).

Comment: I just found out that in English "0 comments" is grammatically right, but the thing is English is not my primary language and in my native language (Portuguese) it it not correct indeed. I just translated the part that says "comments" in order to make it easy since the forum is in English. :)

Comment: and, Mark, I tried that one and it didn't work. :/

Answer (score 6):

You can use Ternary operator **[`(?:)`](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)**

Just check if `get_comments_number` is greater then `1` then it'll be `comments`

Try like this

```
$pego_comment_caption = (get_comments_number($post->ID) > 1 ? " Comments" : " Comment");
```

<kbd>**[`IDEONE`](https://ideone.com/USctVl)**</kbd>

Comment: can we use single quotes in literal strings please :) 
`$pego_comment_caption = (get_comments_number($post->ID) > 1 ? ' Comments' : ' Comment');`

Answer (score 4):

Just add an "or" to the conditional. In PHP, the symbol for "or" in boolean statements is `||` (while "and" is `&&`)

```
if (get_comments_number($post->ID) == 1 || get_comments_number($post->ID) == 0) {
    $pego_comment_caption = " Comment";
}
```

Alternatively, you could set it such that anything less than `1` goes into this, then you'd have:
    if (get_comments_number($post->ID) <= 1) {
        $pego_comment_caption = " Comment";
    }

Alternatively, you could use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to simplify this:

```
if (in_array(get_comments_number($post->ID), array(0, 1)) {
    $pego_comment_caption = " Comment";
}
```

This is definitely useful when you have multiple values you're testing the same variable for (as now if you wanted to say also include 2, you would just add it to the array in the if statement and bam you're set. Less code than the alternative.)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this in your statement

```
if (get_comments_number($post - > ID) <= 1) {
    $pego_comment_caption = " Comment";
}
```